# About ASP .NET 4 and 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So, being new to **ASP .NET** I'm following tutorials to learn it fast. I stumbled upon [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) one that seems pretty complete. I noticed that it says it is using **ASP .NET 5** while mine says **ASP .NET MVC 4 Web Application** when creating the **Solution** (I'm using **Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition**.

I can't find anything related to this, so I don't know if my version supports MVC 5, or if 5 is already there and I just don't see it. Can anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: The MVC project template created in the example link you gave does use MVC 5. It just does not say so in the description when you select the template. But it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 4 is still available in VS2013 under the tab -> Visual Studio 2012.

To get MVC 5 you should pick:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Download [Web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/) and install MVC5 from there.